# Where can you rent Tesla S or X model in Frankfurt?

Tags: car-rentals, frankfurt

Looking to rent Tesla S or X for a 2 week road trip starting in Frankfurt. Any ideas if anybody's renting them? Checking Hertz and Sixt, both no longer list Tesla S in their collection.

### Update (6/6/16):

Got a response from Sixt representative:

> Dear Sherzod Kutfiddinov,
>
> thank you for your e-mail and your
>   interest in Sixt Luxury Cars.   We apologize for the late response.
>   Unfortunately we don't know at which date the Tesla models achieve our
>   fleet. We wait for more informations from Tesla. At the moment we
>   can't say how much they will cost and which models exactly we will
>   get.
>
> We thank you for your patience and understanding.
>
> Do not hesitate to contact us in case of any further questions.
>
> Mitfreundlichen Grüßen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found a Tesla Model S ("or similar", which is what they put on every car, but they say they'll contact you to confirm after you book) from Sixt searching for a pickup from Frankfurt Airport (I randomly used 06/20/2016-06/22/2016) for a mere US$360.71/day.

So they appear to have at least one for rent. Whether it's available under the exact terms you want is something you might need to contact them about.